# Angular passing dynamic entry components into module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have an existing module. How can I write this to support NG 9 with the Ivy compiler as ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS is deprecated?

```
export class DashboardModule {
  static withComponents(components: any[]): any {
    return {
      ngModule: DashboardModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
          useValue: components,
          multi: true
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: In angular 9 entryComponents not required

Comment: So, should I remove the static withComponents part altogether or only remove the providers section?

Comment: You can remove static withComponents method

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks.